# Power BI (DAX) - Month over Month Decliners Calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax

Working in Power BI, I've created a couple of nested measures used to calculate month over month growth.

```
MoM $ Adj CM-1 = CALCULATE ([MoM $],
    ALL ('Calendar'),
    'Calendar'[Relative Month] = "CM-1",
    'Group'[Flag] = "Yes",
    'Type'[Type] = "N/A"
)
```

This works as expected. I am trying to create another measure based on the MoM $ Adj CM-1 measure to calculate the sum of only the negative values so I can see the top declining accounts.

```
Top Decliners = = CALCULATE ([MoM $],
    ALL ('Calendar'),
    'Calendar'[Relative Month] = "CM-1",
    'Group'[Flag] = "Yes",
    'Type'[Type] = "N/A",
    [MoM $] < 0
)
```

This doesn't work (throws an error).

Question is it possible to use the existing measure with an additional filter to sum only the negative values so I can keep all existing filters? Or do I need to write the measure from the base table and reapply all the filters?

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to work on powerbi measures in stack overflow because we can't reproduce your work.

However, I believe you are trying to reference a measure in calculate which normally isn't allowed with out a `filter` wrapper.

Rather than trying to incorporate filter in your answer, may I suggest you create a new "root" measure of negative only MoM measure and then reference that measure in the same way as your first formula?

If you want to use filter then try the below. Depending on the base measure is calculated, you need to validate if the results are correct:

```
Top Decliners = CALCULATE ([MoM $],filter(
    ALL ('Calendar'),
    'Calendar'[Relative Month] = "CM-1",
    'Group'[Flag] = "Yes",
    'Type'[Type] = "N/A",
    [MoM $] < 0)
)
```

Comment: I've updated the answer with a filter version of the response. If you found this helpful, please consider selecting this as the answer or upvoting @mike